# What case follows "fond of"?

Tags: prepositions, history, grammatical-case

What case is "I am fond of her"? Dative or possessive? My thought is that this form comes from the Anglo-Saxon, which is still heard in German, for example "ich bin derren bewusst" (I am hers aware) or "ihret wegen" (hers because).

Comment: Wouldn't grammatical case be associated with the 'noun' (noun/pronoun/etc) rather than the verb?

Comment: When I Google [Dative or possessive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Dative+or+possessive&oq=Dative+or+possessive&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) all I get is a shedload of results about ***German***. I don't think this is a meaningful concept in English today.

Comment: There's no case here. "Of" is not a genitive case marker, thus "of her" is simply a complement of the verb. It's no different to "I am fond of fish".

Comment: My fingers won't stop... If you're too possessive, you may not get another dative, however fond of her you are.

Comment: English nouns do not have case. Only a few English personal pronouns. In any event, _(be) fond (of)_ is a (transitive) predicate adjective, not a noun.

Comment: I think it is the "of her" that the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Modern English doesn't have any morphological distinction between a "dative"-case form and the "accusative"-case form. Because of this, the concept of a particular construction or preposition governing the "dative" case (as opposed to the accusative case) doesn't make sense in English the way it does in German. (The word "dative" is sometimes used when talking about English *syntax* or semantics: e.g. the term "dative alternation" or "dative shift".)

"I am fond of her" clearly does not contain the possessive pronoun "her" that is found in a phrase like "her book", because we don't say things like "She is fond of my" or "I am fond of his": we would say "She is fond of me" and "I am fond of him".

Answer (score 0):

It's accusative case.

You don't say "I am fond of she" (nominative) or "I am fond of hers" (possessive)

> I am fond of her

is like

> We are angry at them.

or

> You are unsure about us.

following the pattern 'NounPhrase ToBE ADJ PrepositionalPhrase'. Not all adjectives work, and each adjective has it's own idiosyncratic preposition, but whatever the preposition, if the object is a pronoun, it will be in *accusative* case.

Prepositions in English take accusative case and this only really shows up in pronouns. 'above me', 'next to him' , 'among us', 'of her'. English doesn't have a dative case. Old English (or Old Anglo-Saxon) had a lot more cases, very similar to Old German which did not lose its cases. In older Germanic languages, some prepositions took accusative, mostly dative, and a few genitive (what is called  possessive in English).